# abc_ic_ab_back_material resource not found in support library 23.2.1

Tags: android, android-support-library

After updating android support library `23.2.0` to `23.2.1` there is an error of `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material` not found.

**What is the updated resource used in version `23.2.1` ?**

Comment: These are private resources you shouldn't be using. Better to create your own resources.

Comment: yes.. I realized it because it is changing over time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After researching some time I found that in version `23.2.1` google again introduced the `drawable R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` which is removed in `23.2.0`.

So, changing to `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` from `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material` solve my problem.

Comment: I'm using support library `25.1.0`. On (some or all?) pre-L devices `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material` can be found. This causes a `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`. So maybe the best solution is to not use this _private_ resource and copy the image into your app's resources.

Comment: How do I "change" it? The build directory is complaining and every time I change the build files and sync again, it goes back to the old value

Answer (score 2):

1- Use `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material` instead of `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha`

2- in your build.gradle add the bellow value:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  

android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

3- Use "srcCompat" attr instead of "src" in all xml:

```
<ImageButton xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/back_button_bar"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material"/>
```

*don't forget to use another attr resource like this xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"*

4- Add next line in your application class

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

5- Google recomend copy the R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material and paste in your project.

*source*: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my vector drawables.
I used image vector drawable importer tool of Android Studio.
it makes the object in

> res>anydpi>myobject.xml

The problem solved by copying the drawable into

> res>drawable

Folder.

Comment: can you tell more specifically how to use that tool?