# Error in support library 23.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I updated the support library to 23.2.1 of my android studio and got this error

> Error:(67, 54) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:actionModeCloseDrawable' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha').
>
> i have tried solutions given but as i change  to (abc ic_ab_back_material) n build it ..

The change i did automatically got change to previous one.. maybe its due to its DEBUG directory.
what should be done
i have tried change in grade file

Comment: sry tht actually was 23.2.1 in which i m getting error

Comment: Please check the appcompat compile android sdk version, it should be 23.2.1

Comment: checked n ya it is 23.2.1

Comment: I got also same problem. **Check this** : [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35966649/1263362)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie so i found one solution n it worked for me.. I just put a vector drawable file in drawable folder with same name n it worked !